# Why can't I upgrade my units in Heroes VI?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I've played quite a few campaign missions but none of them allow me to build the buildings for upgraded troops, even after having built everything else possible in a city or town.  For example, I can get sentinels and crossbowmen, but the option to build the building which would enable me to get praetorians or marksmen never shows up! It's happening for all races.

Comment: Have you confirmed you have all the resources necessary for the building?  A lot of the buildings have high crystal requirements and there often isn't much crystal available on the maps.

Comment: @Jason There is a difference in display between a building you don't have enough resources for, and a building that you are unable to build because it is locked.  The latter just doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @bwarner - Ah.  It's been too long since I played, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

during the campaign, some buildings and upgrades are locked. As you progress through the campaign, they'll open up, sometimes during a mission after completing specific quests, sometimes on the next map.